# node sharing data between server & client

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Is there a way using node & socketIo/express to somehow bind an object variable to the client side so it behaves like reactive meteor and stays synchronized the way meteor does it?

in other words, for example i have a JSON object-variable in my node.js script:

```
var marksObject = {
    firstValue   : 'this is the first value' ,
    secondValue  : 'this is the second value'
};
```

i am looking for a simple way have marksObject appear to be in both the client and the node-server and synchronized. so if a change happens on either the client or the node-server, the change appears to happen in both places.

ideally this would only involve a few lines of code, and i would not have to write anything to manually keep the client&node-server in sync.

Redis looks very interesting but seems like overkill for what i am attempting.

thank you very much.

Comment: You can also take a look at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), it is a Framework to quite easily build real time applications. One of its main advantages is that it enables you to share code between the server and the client side.

Answer (score 4):

it would appear that [deepstream.io](http://deepstream.io) does exactly this for us with a minimal amount of effort.

deepstream server:

```
var DeepstreamServer = require('deepstream.io');
var server = new DeepstreamServer();
server.set('host', '192.168.123.123');
server.set ('port', 6020 );
server.set ('tcpPort', 6021 );    
// this is the default, but its a nice reminder
server.start();
```

node "client"  (runs on server but behaves just like a client):

```
var deepstream = require('deepstream.io-client-js');
ds = deepstream( '192.168.123.123:6021' ).login();   
// port has to match tcpPort or just use 6021
record = ds.record.getRecord( 'clientRecord' );
record.set('clientField', 'test from the node client running on the server! ');
record.subscribe ('clientField' , function (value)  {
            console.log('subscribed value: ' + value)
});
```

browser "client" to be ran in one or more browsers

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='deepstream.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
ds = deepstream( '192.168.123.123:6020' ).login();
record = ds.record.getRecord( 'clientRecord' );
record.set ('clientField', 'test test from a browser!');
record.subscribe ('clientField' , function (value)  {
            console.log('subscribed value: ' + value)
});
//   for fun, enter     record.get('clientField');  in the console too
//   and also enter    record.set('clientField', 'this is what i entered in the console!');
</script>
```

Comment: btw: you can run deepstream from a CLI now, so you can replace the first code snippet with `./deepstream start`, port 6020 and 6021 are default values, the IP will default to 0.0.0.0, so all network interfaces can access the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just write some wrapper class with getters and setters. And on "set" send updates to other side.

Comment: would this approach automatically sync the JSON structure between the client and the server?

Comment: Sure. Thats what you will implement.